# Getting Mockito Exception : checked exception is invalid for this method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, checked-exceptions

I have a method which I am trying to test

```
public List<User> getUsers(String state) {

        LOG.debug("Executing getUsers");

        LOG.info("Fetching users from " + state);
        List<User> users = null;
        try {
            users = userRepo.findByState(state);
            LOG.info("Fetched: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(users));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info("Exception occurred while trying to fetch users");
            LOG.debug(e.toString());
            throw new GenericException("FETCH_REQUEST_ERR_002", e.getMessage(), "Error processing fetch request");
        }
        return users;
    }
```

Below is my test code:

```
@InjectMocks
    private DataFetchService dataFetchService;

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

@Test
    public void getUsersTest_exception() {
        when(userRepository.findByState("Karnataka")).thenThrow(new Exception("Exception"));
        try {
            dataFetchService.getUsers("Karnataka");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            assertEquals("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
    }
```

Below is my UserRepository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

public List<User> findByState(String state);
}
```

When the run my test as Junit test, it gives me following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: java.lang.Exception: Exception occurred
```

Any idea on how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message is extremely specific: Your `findByState` method can't throw `Exception`. Note in particular that (1) you should catch the most specific exception possible, in this case `DataAccessException`, and (2) it's harmful to troubleshooting to mask the underlying exception; make sure to use the chained constructor that takes `Throwable cause`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should use `RuntimeException` or subclass it. Your method has to declare checked exception (example: `findByState(String state) throws IOException;`) otherwise use `RuntimeException`:

```
 when(userRepository.findByState("Karnataka"))
       .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Exception"));
```

Comment: Can someone explain why Mockito doesn't allow us to mock with Checked Exceptions?

Answer (score 17):

If you can modify the source code, then use RuntimeException or extend the RuntimeException.class as @i.bondarekno and @Gayan mentioned

In some cases, we can't change the source code, that time you can use the mockito do answer to throw checked exception.

```
 doAnswer((invocation) -> {
            throw new IOException("invalid");
        }).when(someClass).someMethodName();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the example provided, one should ideally look for a `GenericException`

```
when(userRepository.findByState("Karnataka")).thenThrow(RuntimeException.class);

GenericException exception = assertThrows(GenericException.class, () -> 
                                       userRepository.findByState("Karnataka"));
```